# Branch and bound method for rcpsp

Tags: tree, branch-and-bound, discrete-optimization

How do I construct a tree in branch and bound method to solve rcpsp?

Suppose, I have:
4 tasks that have durations d=[2,3,1,4]
These tasks need resource_amount = [3,2,5,4] of resource that has capacity 6.
And task 3 should be completed before start of task 1 and task 2 should be completed before task 4.

I understand that I need to minimize function f=max{S_i+d_i} where S_i is start time for task i.

I found lots of articles on branch and bound for rcpsp, but the problem is, that most of them don’t give any examples of tree construction, they just say, that I need one

Answer (score 0):

Use heapq (in Python) or any equivalent data structure to build a tree